# static classes for database access?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am using DataClassesDataContext to map all the tables from the db into my asp.net application.

For doing CRUD operations i have made static classes with methods, and inside every method a instantiate DataClassesDataContext.

For instance:

```
public static class UserQ
{
    public static User getUserById(int userId)
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var requestedUser = (from u in db.Users
                             where u.User_id == userId
                             select u).First();
        if (requestedUser != null)
            return (User)requestedUser;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

I aam not sure if this way of doing database operations in a web application is safe?
If not, can you suggest please a better pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the Repository Pattern:

1. [Example 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115232305/http://geekswithblogs.net/AndrewSiemer/archive/2008/02/05/linq-to-sql---implementing-the-repository-pattern.aspx)
2. [Example 2](https://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) (Scott Gu's first chapter from Nerd Dinner - its for MVC but the Repository pattern illustrated works w/o MVC)

Comment: I agree. It really will simplify things and in the case of LINQ to SQL it will increase your performance greatly if you rely on IQueryable.  Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223194/loading-subrecords-in-the-repository-pattern

Comment: Thanks. Haven't heard about Repository Pattern before. After rading the articles i can say: Great!

Answer (score 2):

As DataClassesDataContext implements `IDisposable`, you should be wrapping it with a using directive:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be very very careful about using STATIC in web applications. Sometimes the bugs are so subtle that you will spend a lot of time debugging.

I think bnkdev & Oded hit the nail on the head: look at repository pattern & wrap your context call in a using statement...

HTH.