# How do I improve ASP.NET MVC application performance?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis

**How do you improve your ASP.NET MVC application performance?**

Answer (score 321, accepted):

A compiled list of possible sources of improvement are below:

**General**

- Make use of a profiler to discover memory leaks and performance problems in your application. personally I suggest [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)
- Run your site in Release mode, not Debug mode, when in production, and also during performance profiling. Release mode is much faster. Debug mode can hide performance problems in your own code.

**Caching**

- Use `CompiledQuery.Compile()`
  recursively  avoiding
  recompilation of your query
  expressions
- Cache not-prone-to-change
  content using `OutputCacheAttribute`
  to save unnecessary and action
  executions
- Use cookies for frequently accessed non sensitive information
- Utilize [ETags](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+mvc+etag) and expiration - Write your custom `ActionResult` methods if necessary
- Consider using the `RouteName` to organize your routes and then use it to generate
  your links, and try not to use the expression tree based ActionLink method.
- Consider implementing a route resolution caching strategy
- Put repetitive code inside your `PartialViews`, avoid render it *xxxx* times: if you
  end up calling the same partial 300 times in the same view, probably there is something
  wrong with that. [Explanation And Benchmarks](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/17/how-to-improve-the-performances-of-asp.net-mvc-web-applications.aspx)

**Routing**

- Use `Url.RouteUrl("User", new { username = "joeuser" })` to specify routes. [ASP.NET MVC Perfomance by Rudi Benkovic](http://www.slideshare.net/rudib/aspnet-mvc-performance)
- Cache route resolving using this helper `UrlHelperCached` [ASP.NET MVC Perfomance by Rudi Benkovic](http://www.slideshare.net/rudib/aspnet-mvc-performance)

**Security**

- Use Forms Authentication, Keep your frequently accessed sensitive data in the 
  authentication ticket

**DAL**

- When accessing data via LINQ [rely on IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106802/why-use-asqueryable-instead-of-list)
- [Leverage the Repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223194/loading-subrecords-in-the-repository-pattern)
- Profile your queries i.e. [Uber Profiler](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/UberProf)
- Consider second level cache for your queries and add them an scope and a timeout i.e. [NHibernate Second Cache](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.html)

**Load balancing**

- Utilize reverse proxies, to spread the client load across your app instance. (Stack Overflow uses [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) ([MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?casestudyid=4000006676)).
- Use [Asynchronous Controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee728598(v=vs.98).aspx) to implement actions that depend on external resources processing.

**Client side**

- Optimize your client side, use a tool like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for
  suggestions to improve performance
- Use AJAX to update components of your UI, avoid a whole page update when possible.
- Consider implement a pub-sub architecture -i.e. Comet- for content delivery against
  reload based in timeouts.
- Move charting and graph generation logic to the client side if possible. Graph generation
  is a expensive activity. Deferring to the client side your server from an
  unnecessary burden, and allows you to work with graphs locally without make a new
  request (i.e. Flex charting, [jqbargraph](http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/), [MoreJqueryCharts](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/)).
- Use CDN's for scripts and media content  to improve loading on the client side (i.e. [Google CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/))
- Minify -[Compile](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)- your JavaScript in order to improve your script size
- Keep cookie size small, since cookies are sent to the server on every request.
- Consider using [DNS and Link Prefetching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching) when possible.

**Global configuration**

- If you use Razor, add the following code in your global.asax.cs, by default, Asp.Net MVC renders with an aspx engine and a razor engine. This only uses the RazorViewEngine.

  `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());`
- Add gzip (HTTP compression) and static cache (images, css, ...) in your web.config 
  `<system.webServer>
      <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
   </system.webServer>`
- Remove unused HTTP Modules
- Flush your HTML as soon as it is generated (in your web.config) and disable viewstate if you are not using it
  `<pages buffer="true" enableViewState="false">`

Comment: wait you mean i do lose performance when i e.g. have a view that displays a result set by irritating through an IList and call Render.PartialView("Row", item) for each list item? how much do i lose? or how could i measure the performance gain?

Comment: @SDReyes - what is the meaning of **pub-sub architecture**?

Comment: This is cool.  Uber Profiler link is dead though.  Should this be linked to one of the ORM specific profilers instead?

Answer (score 12):

The basic suggestion is to follow [REST principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and the following points ties some of these principals to the ASP.NET MVC framework:

1. Make your controllers [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Constraints) - this is more of a '*Web* performance / scalability' suggestion (as opposed to micro/machine level performance) and a major design decision that would affect your applications future - especially in case it becomes popular or if you need some fault tolerance for example.

   - Do not use Sessions
   - Do not use tempdata - which uses sessions
   - Do not try to 'cache' everything 'prematurely'.
2. Use [Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-03-cs.aspx)

   - Keep your frequently accessed sensitive data in the authentication ticket
3. Use cookies for frequently accessed non sensitive information
4. Make your [resources cachable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Constraints) on the web

   - [Utilize ETags](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net%20mvc%20etag)
   - Use expiration
   - Write your custom ActionResult classes if necessary
   - Utilize [reverse proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)
5. Compile your JavaScript. [There is Closure compiler library](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) to do it as well (sure [there are others, just search for 'JavaScript compiler'](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20compiler) too)
6. Use CDNs (Content Delivery Network) - especially for your large media files and so on.
7. Consider different types of storage for your data, for example, files, key/value stores, etc. - not only SQL Server
8. Last but not least, test your web site for performance

Answer (score 10):

[Code Climber](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/17/how-to-improve-the-performances-of-asp.net-mvc-web-applications.aspx) and [this blog entry](http://blog.whiletrue.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-performance/) provide detailed ways of increasing application's performance.

Compiled query will increase performance of your application, but it has nothing in common with ASP.NET MVC. It will speed up every db application, so it is not really about MVC.

Answer (score 8):

This may seem obvious, but run your site in Release mode, not Debug mode, when in production, and also during performance profiling. Release mode is *much* faster. Debug mode can hide performance problems in your own code.

Answer (score 6):

Not an earth-shattering optimization, but I thought I'd throw this out there - [Use CDN's for jQuery, etc.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx).

Quote from ScottGu himself: The Microsoft Ajax [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) enables you to significantly improve the performance of ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC applications that use ASP.NET AJAX or jQuery. The service is available for free, does not require any registration, and can be used for both commercial and non-commercial purposes.

We even use the CDN for our webparts in Moss that use jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

When accessing data via LINQ rely on IQueryable ...

[Why use AsQueryable() instead of List()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106802/why-use-asqueryable-instead-of-list)

... and leverge a good Repository pattern:

[Loading Subrecords in the Repository Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223194/loading-subrecords-in-the-repository-pattern)

This will optimize data access to ensure only the data needed is loaded and when only it is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Also if you use [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) you can turn on and setup second level cache for queries and add to queries scope and timeout. And there is kick ass profiler for [EF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework), L2S and NHibernate - http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/UberProf. It will help to tune your queries.

Comment: Ayende recently blogged about how EF Profiler helped him tune a sample MVC app: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/05/17/analyzing-the-mvc-music-store-data-access.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I will also add:

1. **Use Sprites**: Sprites are a great thing to reduce a request. You merge all your images into a single one and use CSS to get to good
   part of the sprite. Microsoft provides a good library to do it:
   [Sprite and Image Optimization Preview 4](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787).
2. **Cache Your server object**: If you have some references lists or data which will change rarely, you can cache them into memory instead of querying database every time.
3. **Use ADO.NET instead of Entity Framework**: `EF4 or EF5` are great to reduce development time, but it will be painful to optimize.
   It's more simple to optimize a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) than Entity
   Framework. So you should use store procedures as much as possible.
   Dapper provides a simple way to query and map SQL with very good
   performance.
4. **Cache Page or partial page**: MVC provides some easy filter to cache page according to some parameters, so use it.
5. **Reduce Database calls**: You can create a unique database request that returns multiple objects. Check on Dapper website.
6. **Always have a clean architecture**: Have a clean n-tiers architecture, even on a small project. It will help you to keep your code clean, and it will be easier to optimize it if needed.
7. You can take a look at this template "[Neos-SDI MVC Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3702cff6-d04e-4aca-bcd8-01d0822de9f7)"
   which will create a clean architecture for you with lots of
   performance improvements by default (check [MvcTemplate](http://www.MvcTemplate.com)
   website).

Comment: Do you think it is better to run one stored procedure which returns more result sets then run more stored procedures in async mode ?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to all the great information on optimising your application on the server side I'd say you should take a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/). It's a superb resource for improving site performance on the client side.

This applies to all sites, not just ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

One super easy thing to do is to think asynchronously when accessing the data you want for the page.  Whether reading from a web service, file, data base or something else,  use the async model as much as possible.  While it won't necessarily help any one page be faster it will help your server perform better overall.

Answer (score 3):

1. Implement Gzip.
2. Use asynchronous rendering for partial views.
3. Minimize database hits.
4. Use a compiled query.
5. Run a profiler and find out unnecessary hits. Optimize all stored procedures which are taking more than 1 second to return a response.
6. Use caching.
7. Use [bundling minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) optimization.
8. Use HTML 5 utilities like session cache and local storage for readonly contents.

Answer (score 2):

1: Get Timings. Until you know where the slowdown is, the question is too broad to answer. A project I'm working on has this precise problem; There's no logging to even know how long certain things take; we can only guess as to the slow parts of the app until we add timings to the project.

2: If you have sequential operations, Don't be afraid to lightly multithread. ESPECIALLY if blocking operations are involved. PLINQ is your friend here.

3: Pregenerate your MVC Views when Publishing... That will help with some of the 'first page hit'

4: Some argue for the stored procedure/ADO advantages of speed. Others argue for speed of development of EF and a more clear seprataion of tiers and their purpose. I've seen really slow designs when SQL and the workarounds to use Sprocs/Views for data retrieval and storage. Also, your difficulty to test goes up. Our current codebase that we are converting from ADO to EF is not performing any worse (and in some cases better) than the old Hand-Rolled model.

5: That said, Think about application Warmup. Part of what we do to help eliminate most of our EF performance woes was to add a special warmup method. It doesn't precompile any queries or anything, but it helps with much of the metadata loading/generation. This can be even more important when dealing with Code First models.

6: As others have said, Don't use Session state or ViewState if possible. They are not necessarily performance optimizations that developers think about, but once you start writing more complex web applications, you want responsiveness. Session state precludes this. Imagine a long running query. You decide to open a new window and try a less complex one. Well, you may as well have waited with session state on, because the server will wait until the first request is done before moving to the next one for that session.

7: Minimize round trips to the database. Save stuff that you frequently use but will not realistically change to your .Net Cache. Try to batch your inserts/updates where possible.

7.1: Avoid Data Access code in your Razor views without a damn good reason. I wouldn't be saying this if I hadn't seen it. They were already accessing their data when putting the model together, why the hell weren't they including it in the model?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add my 2 cents. The MOST effective way to optimize the URL route generation in an MVC application is... not generate them at all.

Most of us more or less know how URLs are generated in our apps anyway, so simply using static `Url.Content("~/Blahblah")` instead of `Url.Action()` or `Url.RouteUrl()` where possible, beats all other methods by almost 20 times and even more.

PS. I've ran a benchmark of couple of thousand iterations and posted results [on my blog](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/263-fastest-way-to-generate-urls-in-an-aspnet-mvc-app/) if interested.

Answer (score 1):

In your clamour to optimize the client side, don't forget about the database layer. We had an application that went from 5 seconds to load up to 50 seconds overnight.

On inspection, we'd made a whole bunch of schema changes. Once we refreshed the statistics, it suddenly became as responsive as before.

Answer (score 0):

Following are things to do

1. Kernel mode Cache
2. Pipeline mode
3. Remove unused modules
4. runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests
5. Don't write in wwwroot
6. Remove unused view engines and language

Answer (score 0):

Using Bundling and Minification also helps you improve the performance. It basically reduces the page loading time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your ASP.NET MVC application on Microsoft Azure (IaaS or PaaS), then do the following at least at before the first deployment.

- Scan your code with static code analyzer for any type of code debt, duplication, complexity and for security.
- Always enable the Application Insight, and monitor the performance, browsers, and analytics frequently to find the real-time issues in the application.
- Implement Azure Redis Cache for static and less frequent change data like Images, assets, common layouts etc.
- Always rely on APM (Application Performance Management) tools provided by Azure.
- See application map frequently to investigate the communication performance between internal parts of the application.
- Monitor Database/VM performance too.
- Use Load Balancer (Horizontal Scale) if required and within the budget.
- If your application has the target audience all over the globe, then use Azure Trafic Manager to automatically handle the incoming request and divert it to the most available application instance.
- Try to automate the performance monitoring by writing the alerts based on low performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of **Task Parallel Library (TPL)**, according to .Net version. Have to choose the correct modules of TPL for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the answers above and it just didn't solve my problem.

Finally, I solved my slow site loading problem with setting **PrecompileBeforePublish** in **Publish Profile** to **true**. If you want to use **msbuild** you can use this argument:

```
 /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```

It really help a lot. Now my MVC ASP.NET loads 10 times faster.