# Tools to measure performance in ASP.net or C#

Tags: sql-server, wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, optimization

Can you please guide me to a book, tool or article that would guide me on how to make an asp.net MVC 2 application that uses WCF to perform better?

I am interested in lower database query time.
How to render pages more quickly.
How to write controllers and action and what are the best practices in order to obtain an efficient application.

I use Asp.Net MVC 2 , NHibernate / Entity Framework, WCF 4.0 and JQuery.

Thanks

Comment: [Likely duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246251/how-to-improve-asp-net-mvc-application-performance).  Also, this site is more for *specific* programming questions.  Good luck on your search =)

Comment: Thanks. But that is not all I want to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the answer you are looking for. I dont think there is a magic tool that will tell you all the problems in all the framework you are using.

> I am interested in lower database query time.

For this, you have to use Sql profiler and go through each procedure/query then optimize.

> How to render pages more quickly.

Try [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) from Yahoo. I cant remember tool name from Google. I will add it latter

Check out Hanselmans podcast with Steve Sodders. [Creator of YSlow on Web Site Optimization](http://hanselminutes.com/288/googles-steve-souders-creator-of-yslow-on-web-site-optimization). They talk about various tools on performance tuning.

Sam Saffron works at Stack Overflow and writes numerous articles on performance tuning. This one may be useful for you. [Profiling your website like a true Ninja](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/06/09/+Profiling+your+website+like+a+true+Ninja)

That's all said, logging is going to be your friend. With good logging, you have more freedom to focus on specific code/component or with AOP tools you can instrument entire app with little code.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add the very easy to use [MVC-Mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/).  It works with MVC and EF.

Comment: I will try this solution soon. It's useful.

Comment: On a second look this tool does exactly what Console and Net tabs from Firebug with some minor tweaks.