# Better loading performance with EF code first and MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, profiling

I am trying to make better (= faster) response in my MVC 4 project and mainly in Web Api part. I added MiniProfiler to see where is problem with slow loading but I can't figure out.

```
                                                    duration (ms)   from start (ms)     query time (ms)
http://www.url.com:80/api/day?city=param (example)  1396.1             +0.0     1 sql   173.8
                                        logging     9.3              +520.9     
                                        EF query    4051.5           +530.2     2 sql   169.6
```

then when I tried same url again I have these numbers:

```
 http://www.url.com:80/api/day?city=param (example) 245.6              +0.0     1 sql   50.6
                                         logging    8.6               +19.6     
                                         EF query   7.7               +28.3
```

but when I tried it after 2 mins later I get again big numbers like in first example.

Same with loading Home Index:

```
http://www.blanskomenu.amchosting.cz:80/    333.0   +0.0    
         Controller: HomeController.Index   71.0    +286.8  
                          Find: Index   100.4   +387.8  
                     Render : Index     2468.1  +494.6
```

This is my method for Web Api in first example

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Hour", VaryByParam = "city")]
    public IEnumerable<RestaurantDayMealsView> GetDay(string city)
    {
        var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
        using (profiler.Step("logging"))
        {
            var logFile = new LogFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/"), DateTime.Today);
            logFile.Write(String.Format("{0},api/daymenu,{1}", DateTime.Now, city));
        }
        using (profiler.Step("EF query"))
        {
            var meals = repo.GetAllDayMealsForCity(city);
            if (meals == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }
            return meals;
        }
    }
```

and my repository method:

```
    public IEnumerable<RestaurantDayMealsView> GetAllDayMealsForCity(string city)
    {
        return db.Restaurants
                 .Include(rest => rest.Meals)
                 .Where(rest => rest.City.Name == city)
                 .OrderBy(r => r.Order)
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(r => new RestaurantDayMealsView()
                     {
                         Id = r.Id,
                         Name = r.Name,
                         Meals = r.Meals.Where(meal => meal.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList(),
                         IsPropagated = r.IsPropagated
                     }).Where(r => r.Meals.Count > 0);
    }
```

for my Home Index I have in my controller just:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

So my questions are:

Why is Rendering of Index taking so long? I have just default website so I think there is no problem with css and other things. [image: Network traffic from IE dev tools]

What is taking so long in EF query when it is not query? How can I fix these problems?

I was looking at these links: [SO list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246628/367593) and [ASP.NET MVC Overview - performence](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/aspnet-mvc-content-map#perf) and I tried some tricks and read about others but nothing help me much. Is it possible that problem is with hosting? Or where? Thanks

Comment: I find EFProf to be invaluable when profiling Entity Framework queries: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf. You could use a free trial just to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a 1+N query issue in your repository method. Using `Include` is only optimized if your don't modify the collection (i.e. use something like `Where` on it). When you do that, EF will re-fetch the records from the database. You need to cast `Meals` to a `List` first, and then run your `Where` clause. That will essentially freeze the pre-selected results for Meals and then filter them in memory instead of at the database.

```
Meals = r.Meals.ToList().Where(meal => meal.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
In your `Repository.GetAllDayMealsForCity()` method:

```
return db.Restaurants
      .Include(rest => rest.Meals)
      .Where(rest => rest.City.Name == city)
      .OrderBy(r => r.Order)
      .AsEnumerable() // <-- Materiazling the query before projection
      .Select(r => new RestaurantDayMealsView()
          {
          Id = r.Id,
          Name = r.Name,
          Meals = r.Meals.Where(meal => meal.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList(),
          IsPropagated = r.IsPropagated
          }).Where(r => r.Meals.Count > 0);
```

You call `AsEnumerable()` before `Projecting` the results using the `Select` method. you have to remember that `AsEnumerable()` is causing the query to 'Materialize' (execute), and because you're calling it before the `Select` method, your query is not limiting the results to the data needed by `RestaurantDayMealsView` only (the further projection is done on an in-memory objects and not on the data store).

Also, your last `Where` could be also appended before the `AsEnumerable()` method.

**2.**
The reason for the significant difference in your profiling results between the first and second hit could be that after the first time Entity Framework is querying for the data from SQL Server, it internally caches the results in memory for better performance.

Comment: I think you are right with first point but still it not helps me much with result loading (it helps with "few" ms).