# Detect high traffic peak in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application that will be hosted on relatively small dedicated server and I'm currently in a process of optimizing its performances (trying to leverage most of the points stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246251/how-do-i-improve-asp-net-mvc-application-performance#2246628), except for the load balancing part, no scaling).
Now I'm expecting that most of the time the traffic will be small and consistent, but on some very rare occasion it could peak.

The question is can this be handled gracefully?
Is there a way how I could detect when there are too much requests that the server cannot handle?
Also in case of detection, is there a way how I could perhaps send a static HTML to new user(s), that would notify him(them) about too much traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure but I believe you're looking for request throttling.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc/1318059) and the provided answers, in short you can use Dynamic IP Restrictions to block unusually high number of concurrent requests and you can use some throttle implementation, if interested see [Throttling Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589798.aspx) for more information.

In case you're not worried about concurrent requests but with the amount of requests in general then the only thing that I would suggest is to limit the number of simultaneous executions of some expensive controller's actions.